# Phonegap Application vs Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm working with Phonegap!

Can I configure Facebook on Phonegap application without having a website?

Let me explain:

- I created an application Phonegap on iOS device
- Then I created an application Facebook to get the App Id.
- When I execute the function `FB.login()`, this error appears:

```
"error": {"message": "Invalid redirect_uri: the url 
 Entered is not permitted by the application configuration"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is trying to access an outside url (maybe facebook.com?) that you might not have whitelisted.

Check out the [whitelist documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).

Comment: I tried but it still does not work, still gives me the same error!

Comment: No i couldn't fixed this.